# Django choices. How to set a option to be selected only once

Tags: python, django

I am working on a blog. I have a section where there will be a special post. And another page where I have collection of special posts. Here is my model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    SPECIAL = (
        ('0', 'Special Post'),
        ('1', 'General Post'),
        ('2', 'Inactive Special Post'),
    )
    specialpost = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SPECIAL, default='1', )
```

Only One post should be in the Special Post. When new special post is added, the old special post should be shifted to Inactive Special Post. So it can be shown in the Collection of Special post page. How can I do this?

Comment: override save method of django model for do this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @neeraj-kumar mentioned in comment, you can achieve this by overriding model's `save()` method. Add to Post class something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        special_post = Post.objects.filter(specialpost='0')
        if self.specialpost == '0' and special_post:
            special_post.update(specialpost='2')
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The new edit works.
Here is what I use: 
`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.specialpost == '0':
            special_post = Post.objects.filter(propic='0')
            if special_post:
                special_post.update(specialpost='2')
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Becareful.. If there is using polomorphic models or nested urls this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you add a new post, filter the query like this `change_actual_post = Post.objects.get(specialpost=0)` and then change the status of your old post `change_actual_post.specialpost = 2` finally save `change_actual_post.save()`.

Add these 3 lines into your views.py file before add a new special post